# Teradata SQL CTE problems - very slow when executing

Tags: teradata, common-table-expression, with-statement

i have a sql script as below:

```
-- Query 1
with 
    ult(col1,col2,col3,col4) as (
    select distinct  t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4
    from table1 as t1
      left join table2 as t2 on t1.Seq_Key=t2.Seq_Key
    where t2.index in 'myvalue')

-- Query 2
select distinct t1.col2,t2.col5,t3.col7
from table1 t1
where t1.col1 in (select col1 from ult)
and t1.col2 = (select col2 from ult)
and t1.col3 = (select col3 from ult)
and t1.col4 = (select col4 from ult)
```

so basically there are two queries inside, and I would like to use the query results from query1 as query 2's condition. I have tried run query 1 only, it will take < 0.1 sec, and run query 2 only(if i manually put the query result from query 1), it will take < 1sec. but if I combined as the above, it will take several minutes to execute! (~4-5 min). I am very curious, and I am not an expert on this. Is there anyone can help to explain what happened and how to optimize the script?

thanks so much!

Comment: I don't even see how this could work. Are you sure that it shouldn't be `t1.col2 IN (...` ?

Comment: In my query, the col1 is a string, that's why I use "IN", and for col2,col3,col4 are a number, that's why I use "=", and it did work for me, though it's quite slow.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.... anyway what you're doing is checking every combination of c1,c2,c3 etc. Is that what you want? so in `table1`, a row could match row 1, col1 of `ult`, and row 9999, col2 of `ult`, and the result will be true. Is that what you want? There is no correlation between the rows in `ult`

Comment: This query will not run at all, if there's more than one row returned by theCTE. Could you simply explain what you actually try to do? Are both `table1` the same table?

Comment: This query did run, though it takes quite long time. Both table1 are same table. basically I have 4 conditions which I want use for the query from table1, but my input is come from table2 (index = myvalue), So I want to based on myvalue @ table2, and get 4 conditions, and then based on these 4 conditions, and query table1 for more data.

Comment: If this query runs then it only returns a single row and then it's the same as `select distinct t1.col2,t2.col5,t3.col7
from table1 t1
where (t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4) in (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from ult)`  But then I don't understand why you need the CTE at all. Additionally the result of the left join is actually an inner join (WHERE-condition on the inner table).